# XPath in RSelenium for indexing list of values

Tags: xpath, rselenium

Here is an example of html:

```
<li class="index i1"
 <ol id="rem">
  <div class="bare">
   <h3>
      <a class="tlt mhead" href="https://www.myexample.com">

<li class="index i2"
 <ol id="rem">
  <div class="bare">
   <h3>
      <a class="tlt mhead" href="https://www.myexample2.com">
```

I would like to take the value of every href in a element. What makes the list is the class in the first li in which class' name change i1, i2.
So I have a counter and change it when I go to take the value.

```
i <- 1
stablestr <- "index "
myVal <- paste(stablestr , i, sep="")
```

so even if try just to access the general lib with myVal index using this

```
profile<-remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//*/input[@li = myVal]")
profile$highlightElement()
```

or the href using this

```
profile<-remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "/li[@class=myVal]/ol[@id='rem']/div[@id='bare']/h3/a[@class='tlt']")

profile$highlightElement()
```

Is there anything wrong with xpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML structure is invalid. Your `<li>` tags are not closed properly, and it seems you are confusing `<ol>` with `<li>`. But for the sake of the question, I assume the structure is as you write, with properly closed `<li>` tags.

Then, constructing `myVal` is not right. It will yield `"index 1"` while you want `"index i1"`. Use `"index i"` for `stablestr`.

Now for the XPath:

```
//*/input[@li = myVal]
```

This is obviously wrong since there is no `input` in your XML. Also, you didn't prefix the variable with `$`. And finally, the `*` seems to be unnecessary. Try this:

```
//li[@class = $myVal]
```

In your second XPath, there are also some errors:

```
/li[@class=myVal]/ol[@id='rem']/div[@id='bare']/h3/a[@class='tlt']
           ^                         ^                       ^
     missing $              should be @class    is actually 'tlt mhead'
```

The first two issues are easy to fix. The third one is not. You could use `contains(@class, 'tlt')`, but that would also match if the class is, e.g., `tltt`, which is probably not what you want. Anyway, it might suffice for your use-case. Fixed XPath:

```
/li[@class=$myVal]/ol[@id='rem']/div[@class='bare']/h3/a[contains(@class, 'tlt')]
```

Comment: thank you. could the syntax of xpath be a little different in Rselenium?

Comment: Maybe. I do not know anything about RSelenium, I just assumed if we are talking about XPath, it complies with the spec.